# routing a network with 2 interfaces and vpns

Tags: cisco, routing, vpn, network

I'm pretty inexperienced in network but here is the idea of what i want to do:

I have 2 interfaces:

Interface #1 = fast internet

Interface #2 = stable internet with static ip address

this is the routing i want to create:

[image]

- Ip group #1 need to use an openVPN connection and it must go through interface #1
- Ip group #2 need to use a PPTP connection and it must go through interface #2
- Ip group #3 need to use an OpenVPN connection (or CISCO VPN connection) and it prefers to go through interface #2
- Ip group #4 need to use a PPTP connection and it prefers to go through interface #2
- others prefer to go through interface #2

can this be implemented in a network? how?

can this be implemented in a single pc? how?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about a PC (host or server) configuration are off-topic here. You could try to ask about that on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for OpenVPN connections is the biggest constraint.  Yes, you should be able to do all that using one Linux box.  You'll want to configure multiple routing tables, or use ip route 2 source-routing features, to help you achieve the desired behavior.  I think the Super User section of Stack Overflow will be a better place for a detailed recommendation.

The biggest thing you haven't specified in your original question / diagram is how the downstream hosts will connect to your router.  Will they all be on one VLAN, or is e.g. IP address group 1 connected via one VLAN, IP address group 2 via another, and so on?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! there is one modem one access point and one simcard modem, downstream should connect through the access point which is both wlan and ethernet connection